# When is a NuGet package compatible with a MAUI app?

Tags: nuget, maui

We want to migrate our app from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. Our app has a lot of dependencies to third-party NuGet packages, so we want to check their compatibility with MAUI in an automated way. The idea is to write a script and query the [registration endpoint of the NuGet API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/registration-base-url-resource) that provides metadata information of a NuGet package, such as the target framework and the dependencies to other packages.

For example, package SkiaSharp (compatible in version 2.88.3) has this [metadata](https://api.nuget.org/v3/catalog0/data/2022.10.04.01.33.24/skiasharp.2.88.3.json) and Sharpnado.Tabs (incompatible in version 2.2.0) has this [metadata](https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-semver1/sharpnado.tabs/index.json).

Is the provided information sufficient to check for a compatibility with MAUI? With regard to a decision logic in a script that classifies any NuGet package as a compatible reference in a MAUI app, what criteria must be fulfilled? Is there a "simple" rule?

Comment: Well if a package supports .net 6+ then it should work with maui more or less

Comment: Alternatively, any package that supports .NET Standard 2.0 or 2.1 is compatible with .Net 6+. Of course, make sure there ISN'T any dependence on any Xamarin package. (Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Essentials, Xamarin Community Toolkit) - any of those refers to namespaces that need to be replaced with corresponding Maui or .Net 6 namespaces. If there is any dependence with `Xamarin` in name, then look at nuget's web page manually.

Comment: No. There is no simple rule to tell you it is gonna work. You have netX.0-android, netX.0-ios, netX.0-mac, netX.0-win. It is perfectly normal to find lib, that works on win port, but does not work on android port. Also, just because something worked in xamarin, it does not mean it will work on MAUI. And last - there are a lot of bugs right now. Some are platform specific.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That's a very helpful comment. Although Microsoft states 'Xamarin.Forms NuGet packages are not compatible with .NET 6+ unless they have been recompiled using .NET target framework monikers (TFMs)', I am guessing that any TFM recompiling would do nothing more than light up newer APIs and that is the reason .NET Standard 2.0/1 NuGets that run on Xamarin would also run on MAUI , despite Microsoft's comment above. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Though its not "DESPITE Microsoft’s comment…": .Net Core 2 code is cross-platform, and is supported by all .Net6+ runtimes. Doesn’t need or use TFMs. Contrast this with XF code, which targets X.Android, X.iOS, etc. Those Xamarin native targets need to be replaced with corresponding .Net6+ TFMs. This would be true even if .Net 6 didn’t introduce newer APIs.